# How Do i create hotkeys which call functions that interrupt eachother?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, hotkeys

If you create a hotkey activated by '1' and a hotkey activated by '2' before hotkey 1's function is finished then the second hotkey won't call it's assigned function.

I can create hotkeys which call functions in python using the keyboard module. I have included an example in the following code which works for calling functions.

```
import keyboard
import time

def hk_print(word,word2):
    time.sleep(5)
    print(word,word)


keyboard.add_hotkey('1', hk_print, args= ('hotkey','test1'))
keyboard.add_hotkey('2', hk_print, args= ('hotkey','test2'))

keyboard.wait()
```

Is there anything I can add to this code to make the hotkey activated functions interrupt eachother? So If I press 1 and then 2 it will stop going through the first function and start doing the second one right away?

Answer (score 0):

It's doable, but it'll take some effort. You're getting into async territory.

What I would suggest is using keyboard.record() and using threading.Timer() in lieu of time.sleep(). You would create a new callback which would start recording all the events as soon as the key is pressed and start a Timer() with some timeout, let's say 5 seconds.

After the time has elapsed, you would have to stop recording, then evaluate the events that were captured during the wait, drop all the 1s and 2s pressed save for the very last one, then call ANOTHER callback - hk_print with the right set of args, depending on what the final press was.